# PCF Spring Cloud Config server not fetching properties from bitbucket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf, spring-cloud-config-server

We have a Spring Task that runs every few mins in PCF, everything works great locally, but once we deploy to PCF and have the properties only in bitbucket, the Spring Cloud Config server doesn't fetch the properties from bitbucket, it connects but it doesn't fetch the properties.

Here is the POM file, we're using Spring boot v2.6.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-service</name>
    <description>Service that does things</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <releaseRepoUrl>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</releaseRepoUrl>
        <snapshotRepoUrl>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</snapshotRepoUrl>
        <deployRepoUrl>${releaseRepoUrl}</deployRepoUrl>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmml-evaluator-metro</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <version>5.2.SP4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <!-- Target basedir directory -->
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/generated/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>${releaseRepoUrl}</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>${snapshotRepoUrl}</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>${releaseRepoUrl}</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>${snapshotRepoUrl}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Are there any dependencies that we're missing? I've tried adding the spring-cloud-task-dependencies version 2.4.0, but no luck.

Your help is appreciated.